# How to collect from a "timestamp without time zone" Field to a Java Timestamp without Timezone

Tags: java, psql, jooq, timezone-offset

My Jooq Query:

```
dslContext.select(
                timeInterval,
                ifnull(avg(field(FieldName.AVERAGE, Double.class))
                        .cast(Double.class), 0.0))
                .from(channelTimebucketQuery)
                .groupBy(timeInterval)
                .orderBy(timeInterval)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Record2::component1, Record2::component2));
```

returns a Timestamp with a Timezone attached to it and a double
[image]

But my Profiler says it should return a Timestamp without timezone.

```
select pg_typeof(time_bucket) from (

    select "alias_67258973"."time_bucket", coalesce(cast(avg(average) as double precision), 0.0) from (select "public"."time_bucket_gapfill"("bucket_width" := cast("public"."create_interval"("seconds" := 43200) as "pg_catalog"."interval"), "ts" := cast("public"."testTable"."time" as timestamp), "start" := cast(null as timestamp), "finish" := cast(null as timestamp)) as "time_bucket", avg("public"."testTable"."average") as "average" from "testTable" where ("public"."testTable"."device" in ('702088'  ) and "public"."testTable"."time" >= timestamp '2020-02-10 13:57:28.2212375' and "public"."testTable"."time" <= timestamp '2020-02-24 13:57:28.2222399') group by time_bucket) as "alias_67258973" group by "alias_67258973"."time_bucket" order by "alias_67258973"."time_bucket"
        ) as x;
```

[image]

Where does the Timezone come from? How do i get the timezone to + 0000

Comment: Better if you could use `timestamp with time zone` in the database and `OffsetDateTime` in Java. The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated. And `timestamp without time zone` is no timestamp, meaning that it does not define a unique point in time.

Comment: An instance of `Timestamp` is just a point in time, it’s independent of time zone (so a completely different beast from an SQL timestamp without time zone, which is a date and time of day). That the `Timestamp` nevertheless often keeps a time zone in it, is very confusing, but you should see it as an implementation detail that is none of your concern (probably an attempt at some optimization, I don’t know). *Conceptually* is hasn’t got a time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default JDBC type for the SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (or just `TIMESTAMP`) is `java.sql.Timestamp`. For historical reasons, which we all regret, `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`, which models a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` by associating your *JVM* time zone (i.e. `TimeZone.getDefault()`) with a unix timestamp.

A much better representation of the SQL `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` data type is `java.time.LocalDateTime`, which jOOQ supports as well. More recent versions of jOOQ's code generator will have set `<javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>` to make the JSR-310 types the default.

Nevertheless, despite the confusion from the debugger and the associated implicit time zone in `java.sql.Timestamp`, the two data types are equivalent to one another, and can be transformed to one another via:

- [`Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime))
- [`Timestamp.toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime())